# crash at AVCaptureDeviceInput if camera is disabled in iOS setting

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am using ZXing widget to scan QRCode. If the user disables camera access from iOS setting, my app will crash like this:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Can't add  because the device does not support AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium.  Use -[AVCaptureDevice supportsAVCaptureSessionPreset:].'

Is there a way to try and prompt user the turn it back on?

Thanks

Leo

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on iPad 1, I'm guessing since iPad1 does not have camera. I did this to work around the crash:

```
if([[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] supportsAVCaptureSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium]){
    // add code to open ZXingWidgetController
} else {
    // show alert that device does not support
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code , it is iOS 5+ compatible

```
- (BOOL)backCameraIsReady
{
    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *inputDeviceError = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *captureInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&inputDeviceError];
    if (!captureInput) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```